# (ls) command won't show exact size - Weird output

Tags: command-line, terminal, directory, ntfs, mate-desktop

I am trying to find the size of the files on my hard drive in exact bytes, but whenever the size gets too big the number turns all weird (like 1.98329e+12). Can I stop it from doing this or convert this into exact bytes?

The command is

```
ls -lR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {print "Total:", total}'
```

Picture of exact bytes: [image: Picture of exact bytes]

Picture of weird number: [image: Picture of weird number]

- The cut-off point before it stops showing exact bytes seems to be around 500gb
- The command `du -sb` properly shows exact bytes no matter how big the directory is.
- I have tried Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 64bit (Japanese and English) and Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64bit (Japanese)
- My drives are NTFS so I tried formatting one as ext4 and copying my files over. The results are same as NTFS.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://askubuntu.com/q/754840/158442

Comment: Please don't crosspost; you're likely to get _both_ questions closed. I strongly suggest you delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with `ls` and everything do with the way numbers are output from `awk`.

The man page for `awk` shows that the default numeric output format is `.6g`, which means a double length floating point number will be output with 6 digits of precision, using either the exponent format (that you see) or a decimal.

You can change this to an explicit output format like this

```
echo 123456789012345 | awk '{printf "Total: %.6g\n", $1}'
Total: 1.23457e+14

echo 123456789012345 | awk '{printf "Total: %.0f\n", $1}'
Total: 123456789012345
```